# can't align rows with kableExtra `cell_spec()`

Tags: r, markdown, kable, kableextra

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r mtcars, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
kable(mtcars %>% 
        select(1:5) %>% 
        head(10) %>% 
        mutate(cyl = cell_spec(cyl, align = "r")), 
      "html", 
      escape = FALSE) %>% 
  kable_styling("striped", "hover", full_width = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(c(1, 3), background = "yellow")
```
````

I [follow the KableExtra guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) to align cells using the `cell_spec()` function. I am trying to *right* align my `cyl` column. But notice the column is not right aligned (image below).

What went wrong?

[image: kableExtra align]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason, the `kable` function itself has an align option. I think if you are not looking for any conditional alignment, you should just use that.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  select(1:5) %>% 
  head(10) %>%
  kable(align = c("crcccc")) %>% 
  kable_styling("striped", "hover", full_width = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(c(1, 3), background = "yellow")
```

For `cell_spec` itself, it seems like right now this align option for HTML just won't give you what you need. If you check the raw HTML generated by this approach, you will see ultimately, `cell_spec` puts your cell into a `<span>` tag. You can specify `text_align` there but that gets overrided by the `text_align` setting in `<td>`. I will see if I should fix this or add a warning note here in this section.

```
<td style="text-align:left;"> <span style="     text-align: right;">4</span> </td>
```

Comment: Thanks. At first the `align = c("crcccc")` looked strange to me until I read kable's man page and read about the `align` argument _"...the string will be expanded to a vector of individual letters, e.g. 'clc' becomes c('c', 'l', 'c'), unless the output format is LaTeX"_.

Comment: @JasonHunter Yeah, btw this "unless the output format is LaTeX" is very important for latex users.